# How to make Error look specific in first microservice that receives it from the first microservice and the rest of microservices to just see 500?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, exceptionhandler

I have a chain of microservices in Spring Boot 'A -> B -> C -> D' (A calls B, B calls C and so on) and when C calls D I want the exception in C microservice logs that it receives from D to look specific that it received from D microservice (for example, "400 Validation Exception" and so on), but in the rest of microservices logs after B calls C and so on I want that exception to be hidden and microservice to just see 500 Internal Server Error generic response.

How do I get that achieved ?

Comment: did you try ControllerAdvice ? `@ControllerAdvice 
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`

Comment: You can also `return` a String/error in each microservice when it's called.